# On click Listener issue

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I am working on Android app in Android Studio and I created Grid Layout with Card view. as on image below:
[image]

I was able to make onClick listener to open my BMIActivity when user click on BMI element in the grid.

Here is my Code for MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.metapall;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout mainGrid;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);
        setSingleEvent(mainGrid);
    }

    private void setSingleEvent(GridLayout mainGrid) {
        for(int i=0;i<mainGrid.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            CardView cardView = (CardView)mainGrid.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    openBMIActivity();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void openBMIActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BMIActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And here is my xml code for mainActivity:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextGird"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="METAPAL"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="34sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="14dp"
        >
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/group"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BMI"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/notes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="CHO" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/piggy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="H20" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/shopping"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Protein" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 3 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Calendar" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:src="@drawable/settings"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Settings" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to figure out how do I open CHOActivity or H2OActivity when these are clicked. Right now which ever button i click it opens up always BMIActivity which I understand is the way i specify. 
But how do I specify to open up correct activity when different button is clicked?
I was trying to use variable i but i am not sure how to bind this with element and then call it within onclick. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Show the XML for `activity_main`

Comment: PPartisan - hi, i just added the XML code as well. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: You can add tag attribute to each CardView like android:tag="H20" and in onClick you can retreive that tag attribute and check like view.getTag()...you can find multiple example of same.

Comment: Or just set the `CardView`'s "id" attribute in the xml (which you're not doing) and use `getId()` and compare against `R.id.xxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WHat you can do is to add tags for each of the cards either via xml android:tag="h20" or through java code view.setTag("h20") while iterating over the view if its dynamically added. call the same click function for all with the arguement as view like openActivity(View view). And inside that switch based on tag like

```
switch(view.getTag){
case "H20:
   doA()
   break;
case "SOMETHING":
   doB()
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have added views manually in layout file,
you should assign id's to your cells (CardViews) and click listeners directly on them.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvBMI"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">
```

.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    GridLayout mainGrid;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainGrid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

        findViewById(R.id.cvBMI).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.cvCHO).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.cvH20).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.cvProtein).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.cvCalendar).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.cvSettings).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.cvBMI:
                openBMIActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.cvCHO:
                openCHOActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.cvH20:
                openH2OActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.cvProtein:
                openProteinActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.cvCalendar:
                openCalendarActivity();
                break;
            case R.id.cvSettings:
                openSettingsActivity();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Harsh Jatinder thank you for this suggestion. I was able to implement this.