# Android OnClick doesn't work with my Cardview

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-cardview

i tried multiple things like `android:clickable="true"`and `setOnClickListener`
on my Cardview but it doesn't do anything. I tried to get any console outputs or anything else. But it seems that it doesn't really recognizes the click on the Button. I also switched the position of the `android:clickable="true"` from parent to child -> no difference.
has anyone any idea? thanks :)

**1. activity_main_menu_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cut_card_background"
    tools:context=".MainMenu">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IFI03"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_TextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:columnCount="7"
        android:rowCount="7">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/menu_it1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryAccent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="IT1"
                    android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        ......
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


       </GridLayout>

 
      </RelativeLayout>
```

**2. MainMenu.java**

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

      CardView it1;
      CardView it2;
      CardView it3;
      CardView it4;
      CardView it5;
      CardView eng;
      CardView pol;
      CardView quiz;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_1);

        it1 = findViewById(R.id.menu_it1);
        it2 = findViewById(R.id.menu_it2);
        it3 = findViewById(R.id.menu_it3);
        it4 = findViewById(R.id.menu_it4);
        it5 = findViewById(R.id.menu_it5);
        eng = findViewById(R.id.menu_eng);
        pol = findViewById(R.id.menu_pol);
        quiz = findViewById(R.id.menu_quiz);

        it1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        it2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        it3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        it4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        it5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        eng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        pol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        quiz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete layout file and the preview screenshot of how the views render on mobile?

Comment: Android Studio got nothing with your problems. Please understand role of tools you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works!

Replace

```
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

With

```
androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

Add this dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to update in Android Support Libraries, **android.support.v7**, causing conflicts and no longer working.. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library

Just make the following change in your xml:

Change

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

to

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

and also in the Activity file import following:

```
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
```

Thats all, Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

[Similar implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809109/on-click-listener-issue) has been answered here.

You can also make setOnClickListener work by setting setOnClickListener to the GridLayout and iterate over the GridLayout view to get the listener to work. This implementation is shown [here](https://virtuooza.com/gridlayout-with-cardview/).

If you are curious about dependencies, this [site](https://www.programmersought.com/article/29147104239/) provides quite a detailed comparison between legacy and androidx libraries, CardView is among them.